# Assigning embedded Struct type values

Tags: pointers, go, struct, embedding

Suppose I have the following struct:

```
type X struct{
    Name string
    Age int
    Email string
}
```

and then I have 2 other structs (subclasses):

```
type A struct{
    *X
}

type B struct{
    *X
}
```

Then in my main code I have:

```
a := A{&X{"John", 34, "jd@email.com"}}
b := B{&X{"Greg", 22, "gd@email.com"}}
fmt.Println(a.Name) // John
fmt.Println(b.Name) //Greg
```

Is there a simple way to assign `a=b` such that `a.Name` returns `Greg` as well as all the other properties (I don't want to assign them individually because there's a bunch of properties)

**Note**: I have to do it this way as I have two identical database tables (in terms of their properties) and the ORM I'm using bases the target table on the struct name. Speaking of, I'm not sure how the ORM identifies the "structure" of the struct to perform this logic, but does using embedded fields, instead of standard fields affect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unqualified type name acts as the field name when embedding, so you may refer to the embedded value as `a.X` and `b.X`.

You may also assign one to the other:

```
a.X = b.X
fmt.Println(a.Name) // Greg
fmt.Println(b.Name) // Greg
```

After this, both will print `Greg`. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ybFyt56kEx6).

One thing to note here. Since your structs embed a pointer, the above assignment `a.X = b.X` assigns the pointer value. So after the above modifying fields of one will affect the other.

So continuing the above example:

```
a.X.Name = "Bob"
fmt.Println(a.Name) // Bob
fmt.Println(b.Name) // Bob
```

Both names changed to `Bob` ([try it](https://play.golang.org/p/ke4T0rHQxRd)). If you don't want that, then assign the pointed values, not the pointers:

```
*a.X = *b.X
fmt.Println(a.Name) // Greg
fmt.Println(b.Name) // Greg
```

This will again print `Greg` twice. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dcYIlowucSA).

And now if you do this:

```
a.X.Name = "Bob"
fmt.Println(a.Name) // Bob
fmt.Println(b.Name) // Greg
```

Only `a.Name` changed, but not `b.Name` ([try it](https://play.golang.org/p/W5ojp1h7lN6)).

Comment: Oh wow, that's handy! I'm guessing then this means the underlying structure of a `struct` with an embedded `X` is different to that of a `struct` if it had all the values of `X` explicitly declared. I ask because I'm using `gorm` which uses a `struct` to represent a table in the database

Comment: @GregPeckory Yes, they are different, but libraries may choose to handle them "equally". When you embed a type, the container struct will have a value of the embedded type explicitly. Fields and methods of the embedded type are _promoted_, but that is just syntactic sugar.